# logging me out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
var account;
var users = ["minibluerhino"];
var password = "killer224";
var gameId = 126945035 //Put your game ID here

for (account = 0; account < users.length; account++) {
    window.location.assign('www.roblox.com');
    $(document).ready(function(){
        document.getElementById("LoginUsername").value = users[account];
        document.getElementById("LoginPassword").value = password;
        document.getElementById('LoginButton').click();
        $(document).ready(function(){
            window.location.assign('http://www.roblox.com/---place?id=' + gameId);
        });
   });
};
```

Whenever I run that code, it brings me to the target location, but I am notlogged in, If I remove the target location, it logs me in perfectly fine.

Comment: why are you looping and nesting ready functions? What exactly do you expect that to accomplish (hint probably not what you think)?

Comment: I just changed your password. Take this as a security/privacy lesson.

Comment: When it Clicks the LoginButton, it loads up a new page so I thought if I wanted for the new page to be ready, it would keep me logged in.

Comment: @Bart that is an ALT account that I use.

Comment: Have you read my answer with its edit?

Comment: @Bart change it back so I can test some more without using my main account? ( I can't just make another account because the account have to be created for more then a day.)

Comment: @sinblade sorry i don't remember what credentials I used.

Comment: @Bart okay, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if i am not mistaken, this should be written more like

```
var account;
var users = ["minibluerhino"];
var password = "killer224";
var gameId = 126945035 //Put your game ID here

$(document).ready(function(){

    for (account = 0; account < users.length; account++) {
        window.location.assign('www.roblox.com');
        document.getElementById("LoginUsername").value = users[account];
        document.getElementById("LoginPassword").value = password;
        document.getElementById('LoginButton').click();
        window.location.assign('http://www.roblox.com/---place?id=' + gameId);
    };
});
```

Or This?

```
var account;
var users = ["minibluerhino"];
var password = "killer224";
var gameId = 126945035 //Put your game ID here

$(document).ready(function(){

    for (account = 0; account < users.length; account++) {
        window.location.assign('www.roblox.com');
        document.getElementById("LoginUsername").value = users[account];
        document.getElementById("LoginPassword").value = password;
        document.getElementById('LoginButton').click();
    };
    window.location.assign('http://www.roblox.com/---place?id=' + gameId);
});
```

Its hard to know what logic your going for exactly?

But the ready function simply means fun this code when the DOM is ready, as in everything on the page has loaded.

The window.location would be called for each loop which does not make sense?

**EDIT:**

I think i understand your problem now more so, Your trying to run this as a script against a web page to auto login you.. Say something like a grease monkey/user script..

The problem here is, Your entering the username and password into the boxes and click "login" as such.. But straight afterwards you are redirecting the browser before it even has time to process the login.

Going to guess a successful login on this site does not auto-reload the page, so hence your attempting this or trying to over ride the default page it loads as your home page.

In this case, you want to either use a setTimeout or handle another javascript on the page that they do load.

If their login does not reload, but simply changes some elements.. Listen to their events and trigger your reload when that happens.

**SECOND EDIT**

Try the following, click did not work on the button.. but because it is a form you can submit it using the form element.

```
var account;
var users = ["minibluerhino"];
var password = "killer224";
var gameId = 126945035 //Put your game ID here

$(document).ready(function(){

    for (account = 0; account < users.length; account++) {
        window.location.assign('www.roblox.com');
        document.getElementById("LoginUsername").value = users[account];
        document.getElementById("LoginPassword").value = password;
        document.getElementById('LogInForm').submit();
    };
   // window.location.assign('http://www.roblox.com/---place?id=' + gameId);
});
```

Being this is a bot, without knowing the further details. This might go against the stackoverflow terms and conditions or something. So going to have to limit what more support i can give.

In general i would suggest if your running scripts to help you login to websites or customize and automate them for you. Have a look at user scripts and you will see they have a world of use.

Have one that gives you a custom GUI or additional elements on a website when your logged in or just simple a script that auto logins you to any site in its list and so on.

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish here is to make a bot, that will automatically login with the tables. After it logs in, It will go to a link for verification for what I'm trying to do, after that it goes to the game link, and tries to 'vote'.

The full code is here: http://pastebin.com/GmAVMViy

Comment: What does this bot run on? Say for example, is it a user script. Is it something you paste into the console of a web browser or?

Comment: I am using the google chrome console, It might take me a little while to test it since I have a captcha from logging in so much.

Comment: Check my second edit, that will get you at least submitting the login and having it redirect to the login page.

Comment: Hm, never thought it would be against the terms, can I have a link to where it might say that.

Also, I would be staying on the same site and just logging into different accounts on the website, and performing the same action on each account.